# Small intro before latest blog posts

Tags: recent-posts

What I'm trying to achieve is quite simple (in my mind).

On the homepage, my blog presents the list of latest posts and I'm ok with it. I just want to add an introduction (three lines of text) before this list of posts.

For some time, I've achieved this by having a fake post with altered publication time (in order to stay first) but now that I'm implementing a newsletter with the latest posts, it starts interfering.

Some ideas on how to fix this? I've already set up a child theme, maybe this come in handy ?

Answer (score 0):

**Two methods:**

**Edit the template file:**

Find the template file that renders your posts (most likely `index.php`) and find the place where the post loop starts.

Something like:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

Any content added before this code will be shown before your blog posts.

**Insert via hook:**

```
add_action( 'loop_start', 'wpse107113_loop_start' );
function wpse107113_loop_start( $query ){
    if( $query->is_main_query() ){
        echo "<p>Hello World!</p>";
    }
}
```